# How do you slide Table column slowly to right in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, easing

I have a table that has six columns.  I am trying to have two of the middle columns hidden at first but then when you click a button, they push the other ones out. Right now I am experimenting with hiding them behind another column with a -z-index and position absolute. I can't get jQuery to animate the transition. Here is the code. It removes the position: absolute and all but it doesn't have a cool transition. The html is just a table, where the TH's have ids and the cells have headers..

CSS:

```
    .hid{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -50;
}
```

and here's the jQuery:

```
$("button#expand").live('click',function(){

    cols =$("#col-1, [headers=col-1], #col-2, [headers=col-2]  ");
    ///this variable gets all the cells of the table column for both 1 and 2

    if($(cols).hasClass("hid")){

        $(cols).removeClass("hid");
        //this works but it doesnt slide 
        $("button#expand").html("Hide");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to animate table rows or columns. You'd have to use individual divs that look like table rows/columns instead.

Comment: I second blaze, but would recommend actually redrawing the table versus just aligning `div`s next to it for accessibility reasons

Answer (score 2):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/8r2qx/)***

What you could do is wrap your content in the table cells with a div like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><div>wrapped content</div></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Once you had done this, you would be able to control the size of that div, and if the size were to be width:0 then the td would show 0. Be careful of a few built in separators such as border-spacing and td padding. Here is a simple way to achieve this:

```
var tds = [];
var hidden = true;
$(".h").each(function(){
 var el = {};
 el.h = $(this);
 el.width = el.h.width();
 el.h.width(0);
 tds.push(el);
});
$("#d").click(function(){
 for( var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++ ){
    var el = tds[i];
    var target = hidden? el.width+"px" : "0px";
    el.h.animate({ width:target });
 }
 hidden = !hidden;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is you can add classes to each  as you construct the table to reference the column they are in. So all cells in column one get the class "col-1", and so on. Then your javascript would simply look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    cols = $(".col-2, .col-3");
    //or which ever columns you want to show
    cols.hide();
    $("#expand").click(function(){
        cols.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

You can see this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5LLJL/).

You could fancy it up a bit by using [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to push the other columns away from the ones that are appearing.

Comment: Another option is to just use [datatables](http://datatables.net/) and apply this [example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html) to your project.